# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init> while running spark based spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, snakeyaml

SnakeYaml jar present at classPath: snakeyaml-1.26.jar

```
2330 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/LoaderOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:607)
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: spring boot version : 2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3.2 should work fine with SnakeYAML 1.26 as that's the version it uses by default. Are you absolutely certain that your application has 1.26 on its class path?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to use snakeyaml in the **exact same version as spring boot** does.

In general a good trick is to import maven dependencies from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` in order to avoid version incompatibilities.

If you're using `mvn`, add this under `<dependencyManagement>` in your pom:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

and then this under `<dependencies>`:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For example spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.6.RELEASE.pom uses snakeyaml in 1.26:

```
 <snakeyaml.version>1.26</snakeyaml.version>
```

Whereas spring-boot-dependencies-2.5.12.pom uses 1.28:

```
 <snakeyaml.version>1.28</snakeyaml.version>
```

And spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.1.pom uses 1.29:

```
 <snakeyaml.version>1.29</snakeyaml.version>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be marked the answer.  In the question, he's obviously importing an outdated version of snakeyml that's not compatible with Spring Boot.  I resolved a very similar error complaining about a missing ParseImpl constructor, and it was because I was importing snakeyaml 1.30 but I needed 1.33

Comment: I was using Spring Boot 2.7.6.

Answer (score 3):

I received this error when I updated snakeyaml from 1.33 to 2.0. **You need to downgrade version to 1.33**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.33</version>
    </dependency>
```

link to mvn repo : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml

Comment: Note, there are vulnerabilities with 1.33 (as of today, march 2023 timeline).  Upvote for the answer.  But it will put you in a catch22 if you do the downgrade.  See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.33

Comment: Are there any known ways of avoiding these vulnerabilities without having to deal with this error?

Comment: Bad solution. you're not thinking about vulnerabilities
Spring boot 3.1.2 and snakeyaml 2.1 works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Please upgrade to 2.7.10 if you are using JDK 11 and no plan to upgrade to springboot 3.x having dependency on JDK 17.

Root cause of the issue is mentioned and [fixed here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34405)

Other solution is to move to application.properties instead of application.yml, so that you will not encounter this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading Jackson to `2.15.0` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping jackson at 2.15.2 and snakeyaml at 1.33 resolved issue for me.

Comment: What about snakeyaml 1.33 vulnerabilities? 
That's not a good solution.